# In Transfer Weight what Does Active Layer Mean?

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

What does active layer mean?
And can we transfer weight for certain vertex group only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active layer is the currently selected vertex group (on source or destination).  Yes, you can transfer weights for individual groups or for all groups (via changing operator "layers", which also allows selected by name.)  If you want to transfer weights for many groups but not all groups, I would just recommend making a quick copy of the mesh and deleting groups you don't want to to transfer, then transferring from that copy.